# Rigify parenting with automatic mesh doesn't keep x simmetry

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

Im trying to rig my first character model, so I set up my rigify metarig in the proper places, made sure the base mesh is symmetrical generated the rig and parented it to my mesh with automatic weights.

However, there is a section of my mesh that just doesn't get assigned any weights by any bones, despite its symetrical counterpart doing so. I have no idea what might be causing this

This is a image of how it looks when all the bones are selected at once.

[image: Weight Paints of all the bones at once]

Comment: This sort of problem is not caused by Rigify itself, usually. It could be something about your character mesh. Sharing your file might be a good idea because this could be due to a number of different factors.

Comment: @CGDive Didn't think of sharing it since it's a nsfw model, and since I posted I just reverted to an earlier stage of the file since I realized I needed to do some changes and starting over didn't replicate the issue. I'll watch out in case it happens again.

Comment: Sounds good to me.